# SOQL: Delete Opportunities before deleting Contacts

Tags: soql, opportunity, contact

I have about 1200 orphan Contacts (not related to any Account).  I want to delete these Contacts, however they have related Opportunities.  So obviously, I need to first delete these opportunities.

I wrote this code to get the Opportunity Id's, so then i can mass delete these opportunities with Data Loader.

However, I am getting 0 records in the opportunity list when I put the condition to get only contact id's from the set. What could i be doing something wrong?

```
List<Contact> con = [SELECT AccountId,AssistantPhone,CreatedDate,Email,FirstName,HomePhone,Id,LastName,MobilePhone,Name,OtherPhone,OwnerId,Phone
                 FROM Contact 
                 Where AccountId = Null AND Email = Null AND HomePhone = Null AND MobilePhone = Null AND OtherPhone = Null AND Phone = NULL];

System.debug('Number of orphan contacts: ' +con.size());   **// 1200, that is correct**


set<string> conid = new set<string>();
 if(conid.size()>0 && conid !=null){
    for (Contact c : con){
        conid.add(c.id);

    }
 }

System.debug('Collecting contact Ids in a Set: ' +con.size());    **// 1200, correct so far** 

List<Opportunity> opps =  [SELECT ID, AccountId,Account_RouteOne_ID__c,CloseDate,ContactId,CreatedDate,DM_Contact__r.id,IsClosed,IsPrivate,Name,OwnerId,RecordTypeId,StageName
                       FROM Opportunity 
                       WHERE DM_Contact__c IN: conid ];        // DM_Contact__c is a lookup to contact   DM_Contact__c = '003E000000y0VY7IAM'


system.debug ('opps size is: ' +opps.size());   **// 0, incorrect**

list<id> oppsidToDelete = new list <id>();
   for (Opportunity o :opps){

      oppsidToDelete.add(o.id);

   }
```

Comment: If you go to one of those Contact records, do you see any Opportunities in a related list?

Comment: Your query looks good, are you sure about the field that on the opportunity object? Also, you don't need to get the Ids by going through a loop. You should be able to do in : con. Also if you're writing the apex, you can just do 

         delete opps;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
set<string> conid = new set<string>();
 if(conid.size()>0 && conid !=null){  // this will always be false!!
    for (Contact c : con){
        conid.add(c.id);

    }
 }
```

you want:

```
set<Id> conid = new set<Id>();
for (Contact c: con) {
    conId.add(c.Id);
}
```

You can actually rewrite this whole class in two statements

```
List<Contact> orphanContacts = [SELECT Id
             FROM Contact 
             Where AccountId = Null AND Email = Null AND 
                   HomePhone = Null AND MobilePhone = Null AND OtherPhone = Null AND 
                   Phone = NULL];
delete [SELECT ID
           FROM Opportunity 
           WHERE DM_Contact__c IN  // assumes DM_Contact__c is a lookup field
             :orphanContacts];
```

This is because [bind variables of list of sobjects will use their Ids where compared to a field of ID type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm?search_text=bind%20variables)

or in one statement using a [semi-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm?search_text=join)

```
delete [SELECT ID
           FROM Opportunity 
           WHERE DM_Contact__c IN  // assumes DM_Contact__c is a lookup field
             (SELECT Id
               FROM Contact 
               WHERE AccountId = Null AND Email = Null AND 
                   HomePhone = Null AND MobilePhone = Null AND OtherPhone = Null AND 
                   Phone = NULL)];
```

Comment: thank you for helping and teaching me.

Comment: @user4947 - no problem; I learned a ton from others on this site; just passing it forward